# Blackpill not sending data after some frame counts (nearly 200-400) through RFM96

Tags: stm32f4, stm32cubeide, lorawan, bluepill

I am trying to integrate an STM32F411 (Blackpill) and an RFM96 LoRa module at the legal frequency in India of 866 MHz.

The problem is that the Blackpill is not sending data after a certain frame count. Sometimes after 250 or 450 frames it stops sending data. Before that it works fine and is sending data and I am able to view it on my gateway. I am not able to figure out why it stops sending data after so many counts.

This is the code I am uploading [github repo](https://github.com/tanujsharma1842/STM32F411-RFM96-lorawan-at-866Mhz)